# Limit of integral (involving sine integral)

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Consider $\phi \in C_c'(\mathbb{R})$. I want to prove that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)dx=\pi \phi(0) \; .
\end{equation}
One could observe that for $M\in \mathbb{R}$ sufficiently large,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\phi(x)dx=\int_{-nM}^{nM}\frac{\sin(y)}{y}\phi\left(\frac{y}{n}\right)dx
\end{equation}
but now how could I manage the limit for $n\rightarrow\infty$ for both the integrand and the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\pi$, it follows that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{nx}d(nx)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}dx=\pi.$$ 
So you are left to prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\left(\phi(x)-\phi(0)\right) dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 
\int_{a}^b\sin(nx)\cdot \frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x} dx=0$$
where $[a,b]$ contains the support of $\phi$.
Now by noting that 
$$F(x):=\frac{\phi(x)-\phi(0)}{x}\sim \phi'(0)$$
you have that $F$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. Finally
use the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma and the proof is complete.